# Figuring the order of integration

Tags: calculus

I have this function $f(x,y,z)=1/3(3x+2y+z)I(0<x<1)I(0<y<1)I(0<z<1)$ and want to integrate over this region s.t. $x>1/2$, $y<1/2$, and $z < 1/2$. So this will be a triple integral. How do I know what ORDER to integrate?

i.e, $dzdydx$? $dxdydz$ ?

Answer (score 0):

Any order you like. All of them will give the same result. Because this definite integral actually represents the volume enclosed by a closed surface, nothing else.

As for example: $f(x,y,z)=\frac{1}{3}(3x+2y+z)$
$$\int f dV = \int  \int \int \frac{1}{3}(3x+2y+z) dx dy dz$$
Here x,y,z are not linked by any function i.e. the restriction on x,y,z are independent, not via any function. So we put the limits directly.
$$\int f dV =  \int_{x=\frac{1}{2}}^{x=1} \int_{y=0}^{y=\frac{1}{2}} \int_{z=0}^{z=\frac{1}{2}} \frac{1}{3}(3x+2y+z) dx dy dz$$

Comment: In general though, if I have a volume of closed space, it will not matter?

Comment: No not all. Try it if you want.

Comment: Fubini theorem.

Comment: As long as the boundaries of whatever space I have does not dependent though. For example, A triangle $f(x,y) = I(0<x<2)I(0<y<1-x/2)$. Then to integrate this function over that region s.t. x>1, y< 1/4, then we have to do $\int_{1}^{2} \int_{0}^{\min(\frac{1}{4}, 1- \frac{x}{2}) } dydx$. Not $dxdy$ because our upperbound depends on our choice of $x$.

Comment: @Aniket Is my reasoning correct?

Comment: Not necessarily. I can write $0<2y<2-x=>x<x+2y<2$ In this way, you can obtain the condition on $x$ due to $y$. Then I can also do $=  \int \int dx dy$ because now my upper bound will depend on the choice of $y$.

Comment: Ah ah okay. Just depends on what we choose then. I see your edit and understand. Thanks <3